# Describing `strace` command output

Tags: linux, php, debugging

I have php process which could not finish for more then 2 days.

```
root     26511  0.0  1.6 407788 27684 ?        Ss   Jul09   0:08 /usr/bin/php action.php
```

This is the output from the strace command:

```
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533745, 664851437}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533745, 664940247}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533745, 665211013}) = 0
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533746, 666594416}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533746, 666684149}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533746, 666772214}) = 0
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533747, 668356163}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533747, 668447565}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {5533747, 668538577}) = 0
```

Can you explain me what this output meaning? Or maybe I can get more informations about the stack process using some other command.

PHP version: PHP 5.4.30 
CentOS release 6.5

Comment: You might find `ltrace` more helpful -- it traces library rather than system calls, giving you a higher-level insight into what's happening.

Comment: @Flup There is an empty output from ltrace, is there some specific usage? I only use `ltrace -p 12345`

Comment: @thanasisk yes, running ltrace as root

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `strace` command lists the systemcalls the application make as it is running.

If you're not de developer: Section 2 of the system manual documents systemcalls helping you understand what is happening.

> `man 2 poll`

```
DESCRIPTION
   poll()  performs a similar task to select(2): it waits for one of a set
   of file descriptors to become ready to perform I/O.
```

The events requested in the poll system call are all read related on file descriptor 7, again from the manual page the events your application is requesting are:

```
POLLIN     There is data to read.
POLLPRI    There is urgent data to read. 
POLLRDNORM Equivalent to POLLIN.
POLLRDBAND Priority band data  can  be  read  (generally  unused  on Linux).
```

The strace lines show the poll action times out, the file descriptor (#7) doesn't become ready for read IO.

The system call `clock_gettime() - clock and time functions` indicate something like wait a little  while and then try again.

To find out which file is causing the timeout, there should be symbolic link with the number 7, the integer representing the file in `/proc/<PID>/fd/7`

Comment: There is a socket as a symbolic link ont fd/4 -> socket:[6249981] (broken symbolic link). How can I continue debugging? @HBruijn

Comment: without a deeper understanding of the expected behavior (in this case: reading the PHP script) it would only be guess work.

Comment: try 'lsof -p <PID> | grep 6249981'.   You will probably find that it's a tcp connection or similar.